# Django form doesn't get processed

Tags: django, forms, post, contacts

When I click the button and the form is valid it just refreshes the page. I checked the POST data it is correct. What can be the problem?

I have a different contact form with the same setup, and it works.

The forms.py file:

```
class ContactFormDebate(forms.Form):

subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
debate_title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
debate_description = forms.CharField()
debate_scope = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
sender = forms.EmailField()
cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

views.py:

```
def contactDebate(request):
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = ContactFormDebate(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        debate_title = form.cleaed_data['debate_title']
        debate_description = form.cleaned.data['debate_description']
        sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
        cc_myself = form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']

        recipients = ['someemail@email.com']
        if cc_myself:
            recipients.append(sender)

        from django.core.mail import send_mail
        message = debate_title.append(debate_descripton)
        send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
else:
    form = ContactFormDebate() # An unbound form

return render(request, 'newdebate.html', {
    'form': form,
})
```

template:

```
<h2 class="page-heading"><span>ПОДНЕСИ НОВА ДЕБАТА</span></h2>
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    <label for="id_subject">Наслов на пораката:</label>
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.debate_title.errors }}
    <label for="id_debate_title">Наслов на дебатата:</label>
    {{ form.debate_title }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.debate_description.errors }}
    <label for="id_debate_description">Опис на дебатата:</label>
    {{ form.debate_description }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.sender.errors }}
    <label for="id_sender">Email адреса:</label>
    {{ form.sender }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.cc_myself.errors }}
    {{ form.cc_myself }}
    <label for="id_cc_myself" id="myself">Сакам да ми пристигне копија од пораката</label>
</div>
<p>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Испрати" class="btn1 btn-primary1" /></p>
```

Comment: Does it return an *empty* form, without the values you enter?

Comment: No, the values I enter are there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re missing a field for `debate_scope` in your HTML.

Also, you have typos for the correct case: `cleaed_data`, `cleaned.data`.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe that the solution is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an else condition if the form isn't valid; you should add that. Secondly, you should make sure your email setup is correct otherwise you will get an exception.

```
def contactDebate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactFormDebate(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            debate_title = form.cleaed_data['debate_title']
            debate_description = form.cleaned.data['debate_description']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
            cc_myself = form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']

            recipients = ['someemail@email.com']
            if cc_myself:
                recipients.append(sender)

            from django.core.mail import send_mail
            message = debate_title.append(debate_descripton)
            send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients, fail_silenty=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
         else:
            return render(request,'newdebate.html',{'form':form})
    else:
         form = ContactFormDebate() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'newdebate.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: My email setup is correct, I successfully send emails from other forms. I added the code you suggested but still same thing happens.